# WCF generates undesired partial class

Tags: c#, wcf

In a separate project/solution I have a class named `CompleteField` that is referenced in multiple WCF projects/solutions.

The WCF generates a partial class from `CompleteField` which is not desired.

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "1.0.0.1")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="CompleteField", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Common.Web.Models")]
public partial class CompleteField : object
    {
       //...
    }
```

Using the attribute `KnowType` I thought I would be able to omit this behavior (since I have done this in the past).
Below my `CompleteField` class

```
  [DataContract]
  [KnownType(typeof(ValidatorType))]
  [KnownType(typeof(ObjectType))]
  [KnownType(typeof(ICompleteField))]
  public class CompleteField : ICompleteField
  {
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    [DataMember]
    public ObjectType Type { get; set; }
  }

  public interface ICompleteField
  {
    string Name { get; set; }
    ObjectType Type { get; set; }
  }

  [DataContract]
  public enum ValidatorType
  {
    [EnumMember]
    //...
  }

  [DataContract]
  public enum ObjectType
  {
    [EnumMember]
    //...
  }

   public CompleteField(ObjectType type)
   {
     this.Type = type;
   }
}
```

Does anyone know why the WCF still generates the partial class this?

Comment: WCF runtime needs the information which is in this file. It contains informaiton on messages which that WCF services exposes and request/response types which you need to pass on that service. What do you mean they are not desired? do you mean you don't want that? but then how you will communicate with that service then?

Comment: @adeel41 I don't want the WCF to make a partial class of it, because I want to pass an object of CompleteField from my BusinessLayer to it.
Since the namespaces don't match, I'm unable to do pass the object CompleteField

Comment: Can't you pass this object on the client call?why do you say that? as far as I know, The default generated data contract class and service implementation class are partial class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial class is generated because I used a Constructor in `CompleteField`.